# Can we set VSCode Undo (ctrl + z) to undo last change with TWO hits (two times ctrl +z) if last change location is not in the current page?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know in pycharm if we want to undo and the last change location is not in current page, the first ctrl + z would bring you to that location with cursor on it and the second ctrl + z would do the job. Do we have the same feature in vscode?

It is annoying that when I hit ctrl + z and it jumps to some part of the code and undos directly. Sometimes I just wanted to know what was there before undo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few ways to approach this.

- Navigate History <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- Go Back <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / MAC <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
- Go To Last Edit Location <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> / MAC <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>
- Use the command palette to go to recent files
- You could remap CTRL + Z, or more specifically, the when expression, to something less forgiving

I suspect the 2nd/3rd option is what you are looking for

Comment: @HaobingChu see update. I also added one I forgot to include

Answer (score 0):

In VsCode

To reverse your last action, press

> CTRL+Z

. You can reverse more than one action. To reverse your last Undo, press

> CTRL+Y